# update not being done no errors are showing using query builder laravel 4.2

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, query-builder

i have to update a table and change the value inside it and the table have many column inside it. i tried to use query builder and here is my current code

the query is inside the `public function ugetstd($id)`

```
public function ugetstd($id) //update
{
$rules = array(
        'firstname'            => 'required|max:80|regex:/^[\p{L}\p{N} -   ]+$/u',
        'middlename'           => 'required|max:50|regex:/^[\p{L}\p{N} -]+$/u',     //more here

    );
    $messages = array(
        'firstname.required'        => 'First name is required',
        'firstname.max'             => 'First name can only contain 80 characters' //more here
    );

    $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules, $messages);
    if ($validator->fails()) 
    {
        return Redirect::to('view_students/' . $id)
            ->withErrors($validator)
            ->withInput(Input::except('password'));
    }
    else
    {
        DB::table('dbo_students')->where('StudentID', $id )
            ->update
                (
                    array
                    (
                        'FirstName'                     => Input::get('firstname'),
                        'MiddleName'                    => Input::get('middlename'),
                        'LastName'                      => Input::get('lastname'),
                        'CurrentStatusID'               => Input::get('scs'),
                        'Sex'                           => Input::get('sex'),
                        'ReligionID'                    => Input::get('rel'),
                        'EthnicityID'                   => Input::get('eth'),
                        'StreetAddress'                 => $enAdd,
                        'CityID'                        => Input::get('city'),
                        'YearLevelID'                   => Input::get('yearlevel'),
                        'Telephone'                     => Input::get('telephone'),
                        'Birthdate'                     => Input::get('date'),
                        'Birthplace'                    => Input::get('birthplace'),
                        'SchoolLastAttended'            => Input::get('schoollastattended'),
                        'LastGradeCompleted'            => Input::get('lastgradecompleted'),
                        'CurrentModuleLeft'             => Input::get('currentmoduleleft'),
                        'CurrentModuleCriticalLevel'    => Input::get('modulecriticallevel'),
                        'StudentDescription'            => Input::get('description')
                    )
                );

        return Redirect::to('view_students/' . $id);
    }
```

}

the thing is it does not execute the code. it does not update anything and it does not throw any error. any ideas what i am doing wrong? thanks

Comment: Is debugging enabled in your project config? Also, do you have a model for your table?

Comment: yes the debugging is enabled. yup i have a model for the table. should i use it instead of query builder?

Comment: Have you set your `$fillable` array on your model?

Comment: oh i haven't tried that yet. thanks. will try

Comment: @Jyeon As the code is doing a direct update of the database using the `DB` query builder, models have nothing at all to do with this issue.

Comment: @BourneShady - what does the call to update return? It should return the number of affected rows. That won't help much (as it'll probably be `0`) but worth trying. Alternatively, try enabling the DB query log and see what it attempted to execute.

Comment: @alexrussell how can i see the return of the update? sorry im new to laravel

Comment: `dd(DB::table('dbo_students')->where('StudentID', $id )->update(...));`

Comment: i got nothing when i did the dd

Comment: Is your route even being hit? When you trying using `dd()` did your page look the same as before?

Comment: @BourneShady, as Jyeon says, the fact that the call to `dd()` doesn't give any output suggests that the method in which you call it is not even being called (as `dd` should dump whatever you pass to it and then immediately exit PHP execution). So that would be why the update doesn't happen too. Check that the routing is set up to hit that `ugetstd()` method.

Comment: it went inside the ugetstd method and i have several validations there and an if else function. i'll update my question and put the codes there thanks much

Comment: hi guys! i finally made it work turns out i dont have a input called city it was supposed to be cty. the dd said i have some query error. thanks @alexrussell

Comment: hi guys! i finally made it work turns out i dont have a input called city it was supposed to be cty. the dd said i have some query error. thanks @Jyeon